# Program to count the number of bits set in c

Tags: c

I have tried to count the number of bits set in an integer value in C.
But for some values it is showing the correct bit set count and for some values it is not.

PFB program code

```
int main()
{
    int a = 512, i = 0, j = 1, count = 0, k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    {
        if (k = a & j)
        {
            count++;
            j = j << 1;
        }
    }
    printf("the total bit set count is %d", count);
}
```

The output of set bit value count of 512 is showing as zero and if the value used is 511 count is showing as 9.

Please help me to correct the program.

Comment: An `int` does not necessarily have 32 bits. And in general, for bitshift, it is better to use unsigned integers.

Comment: `int cnt; uint32_t k; k = ...; for ( cnt = 0 ; k ; k >>= 1 ) if ( k & 1 ) cnt++;` There is a better algorithm, just do some research on your own (takes 1-2 minutes).

Comment: Did you try basic debugging with your program ? (For example by inserting  some printfs at strategic places in your program)

Comment: if(k=a&j) is logically incorrect. You want == rather than = .  One "=" is assignment, two "==" is test for equality.

Comment: I just use k variable to display the result of bit operation a&j when using GDB

Comment: Compiler warnings are there for good reason. Enable them and handle all reports before asking!

Comment: After modifying the program by adding an else statement.It started to work correctly.                                                                                     if(a&j)
                {
                count++;
                j=j<<1;
                }
                else
                j=j<<1;

Answer (score 7):

Stanford University has a page of different ways to implement common bit-twiddling operations. They list 5 different algorithms to count the bits set, all with C examples.

https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive

Their simplest implementation:

```
unsigned int v; // count the number of bits set in v
unsigned int c; // c accumulates the total bits set in v

for (c = 0; v; v >>= 1)
{
  c += v & 1;
}
```

Comment: Just for future reference, posting a link as an answer is frowned upon because there is no guarantee that the link will exist tomorrow making the answer worthless to anyone after that has occurred. Provide the examples and explain them, or post the link as a comment.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 6):

If you're using gcc/clang compiler, you can use the builtin function **__builtin_popcount**

```
unsigned int user_input = 100
int count = __builtin_popcount(n); // count == 3
```

When I'm not looking for cross-platform I'll use this function since its highly optimised.

Answer (score 4):

Generally you would count bits in an unsigned integer. The reason being that you're usually checking for bits set in a register or a mask, for example. Signed integers are represented using [***two’s-complement***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and I can’t think why you'd want to count set bits in a signed integer (would be interested why if you definitely do want this).

Note in C that right or left shifting a signed integer is **implementation defined behaviour** if the number is negative. From C standard section 6.5.7:

> ... The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; ... If E1
> has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 << E2 is representable
> in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined.**
>
> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2
> bit positions. ... **If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
> resulting value is implementation-defined** ...

If you want to count 1’s in an arbitrary sized **unsigned** integer you could use [***this example***](https://ideone.com/blP1ri):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   unsigned int value = 1234;
   unsigned int ones = 0;
   while(value > 0) {
      ones += value & 0x1;
      value >>= 1;
   }
   printf("#Ones = %u", ones);
}
```

Using this example `value` could be unsigned char, unsigned long, whatever unsigned integer type...

Note: Do not shift signed values or floats/doubles.

Comment: I have tried this program to learn the bit wise operations and bit arrangement  of a variable in c.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the division `/` and the modulo `%` operator to check the bits that are set in an integer.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 512, count = 0;

    while(a != 0)
    {
        if(a % 2 == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
        a /= 2;
    }
    printf("The total bit set is %d", count);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this way also and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: Unless the compiler is really good and optimizes knowing `a` is never negative, code will to do a remainder call on  `a % 2` that results in `0,1, or -1` and then a compare against 1.  In such a case `if(a % 2)` could yield simpler code. - or even `if (a & 1)`.  Yet I suspect you are trying to emphasize code clarity over niched performance.  Note: if `a` started as negative, the result would be 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the value of `a&j` , and if `a&j` is 0, then you do nothing else but try again.

Your `j`-bitshift needs to be outside the if-then.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of mistakes:

```
for(i=0;i<32;i++) // <<< this should be 32, not 31
{
    if(k=a&j)
    {
        count++;
    }
    j=j<<1;       // <<< this needs to be outside the if block
}
```

Note that instead of using a hard-coded value of 32 for the no of bits in an `int`, it would be better to do it like this:

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT;i++)
```

This way the code will still work if the size of an `int` is e.g. 16 bits or 64 bits.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the CHAR_BIT value.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` is a constant defined in `limits.h` that defines the number of bits per-byte (or bits per `char`). It is generally `8`. It prevents hardcoding that value in your code. Above `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` is `4 * 8 = 32`.

Comment: Although often not an issue, the 2nd to last shift of `j=j<<1` is a worrisome UB.

Comment: @chux: can you expand on that - I don't see a UB issue but I may be missing something obvious ?

Comment: "If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is  representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." C11 §6.5.7 4 is a way of saying that shifting into the sign bit is UB. `int j = 0x40000000; ... j = j << 1` is the candidate problem.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know that - I was going to mention that using unsigned types is generally a good idea when you're doing bit twiddling stuff but someone else had already covered that in another answer/comment so I didn't bother repeating it.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not C strictly speaking, you can use inline assembly to call the `POPCNT` x86 operation:

```
// GCC syntax
unsigned a = 1234;
unsigned int count;
__asm__( 
    "  POPCNT %0, %1\n"
    :"=r" (count)
    :"r" (a)
);
return count;
```

According to [this benchmark](https://github.com/BartMassey/popcount), calling `__builtin_popcount` as in [idok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60261154/898783) is just as fast as the above code and they both are much faster than any other C implementation. You can also check the linked repo for other solutions as well.

Comment: *this is not C strictly speaking...* nor loosely I'm afraid :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int rem, binary = 0;
unsigned int

countSetBits (unsigned int n){

    unsigned int count = 0;

    while (n){
        count += n & 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }

    printf ("\n\t Number of  1's  in the binary number is : %d",count);
}

int dec_bin (int n){

    int i=1;

    while (n != 0){
        rem = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        binary = binary + (rem * i);
        i = i * 10;
    }

    printf("\n\t The converted Binary Equivalent is : %d",binary);
}

int main(){  
    int i = 0;

    printf ("\n\t Enter the Decimal Nummber: ");

    scanf ("%d", &i);

    int n= i;
    dec_bin(n);
    countSetBits (i);
    return 0;
}
```